# Fast transpose of sparse matrix

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sparse{
    int r;
    int c;
    int n;
}sparse;

void fastranspose(sparse s[],sparse ts[]);
void create(sparse s[]);
void display(sparse s[]);

void create(sparse s[])
{
    printf("enter the rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&s[0].r,&s[0].c,&s[0].n);
    for(int i=1;i<=s[0].n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d",&s[i].r,&s[i].c,&s[i].n);
    }
    display(s);
}

void fastranspose(sparse s[],sparse ts[])
{
    int starting[50],count[50];
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        starting[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        count[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=s[0].n;i++)
    {
        count[s[i].c]++;
    }
    starting[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<s[0].c;i++)
    {
        starting[i]=starting[i-1]+count[i-1];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=s[0].n;i++)
    {
        int p=starting[s[i].c];
        starting[s[i].c]++;
        ts[p].r=s[i].c;
        ts[p].c=s[i].r;
        ts[p].n=s[i].n;
    }
    ts[0].r=s[0].c;
    ts[0].c=s[0].r;
    ts[0].n=s[0].n;
    display(ts);
}

void display(sparse s[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s[0].r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s[0].c; j++) {
            int found = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= s[0].n; k++) {
                if (i == s[k].r && j == s[k].c) {
                    printf("%d ", s[k].n);
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                printf("0 ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    sparse s1[100];
    sparse ts1[100];
    create(s1);
    fastranspose(s1,ts1);
}
```

I wrote a program to find the fast transpose a sparse matrix according to the algorithm, it should perform a transpose, but it isn't performing it correctly.  I tried to dry run it, but unable to find a mistake.  My input sparse matrix was:

```
2 3 3
0 0 3
0 2 5
1 1 4
```

expected output:

```
0 3 
4 0 
0 5
```

Output:

```
0 3
0 4
5 0
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use a debugger to see the actual steps it takes.

Comment: Couldn't `fastranspose()` just copy the sparse matrix and exchange all the `r` and `c` member values?

Comment: The input matrix is [[3,0,5],[0,4,0]], so shouldn't the transposed matrix be [[3,0],[0,4],[5,0]]? That differs from both your expected output and actual output.

Comment: The simplest transpose code I can come up with is `for (int i=0; i <= s[0].n; i++)` `{` `ts[i].r = s[i].c;` `ts[i].c= s[i].r;` `ts[i].n = s[i].n;` `}`.

Comment: I would suggest instead of scaning user input to create the test array. Also use the correct type for sizes (size_t)

Comment: You seem to be mixing paradigms here.  If you want fast sparse-matrix operations on your array-based representation then you need to impose an ordering scheme on the elements that supports that purpose.  Your input function does not ensure such an ordering, and your display function does not rely on it (and therefore is much slower than it might otherwise be).  Your transpose is far more costly than it needs to be for an unordered sparse-matrix representation.